# String or string literal fails

Tags: racket

I am trying something simple to follow exercises in a book. For example, typing “hello” at the prompt in the interactions window.

I get the the following error:

`“a”: unbound identifier in module in: “a”`

I believe simple things like this worked before, so I want to know what to check to resolve this problem.

Comment: I doubt that typing `"hello"` caused an error message about `“a”`. Also, the interactions window does not produce error messages of that form when you interact with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem are the quotation marks, a very common problem. Look:

`“a”`

The quotation marks look italic.
They should be like this: `"a"`.

Copy paste this into your REPL and print return (this time it will work!):

```
"hello"
```

This is written with the right quoation marks `""` and not `“”` .
If you copy paste from pdf books somteims this wrong quotation marks appear as a result (like Realm of Racket - because recently I had that problem when copy pasting from it). (Quotation marks from MS Word when using Times Romans fonts are also from this strange type, and in some programming blogs, too, the quotation marks are spoiled when copy pasting out of them).

How to avoid it?: Type the examples manually into the DrRacket editor. - problem solved! Plus you learn the things anyway much better if you type them yourself - ("the hard way" approach ;) ).

And you learn, that even copy pasting is a skill which one sometimes has to learn anew - welcome to programming (the long road of learning) :D .

Comment: I actually was trying to go through some exercises in Programming Racket Visually by Stephen Bloch.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to enter the quotes " around the hello too.

```
"hello"  is a string which contains the text hello
hello    is a name of an variable (an identifier),
         so if you haven't defined the name hello you get an
         error saying that the identifier is undefined
```

[image]

Comment: > “hello”
. . “hello”: undefined;
 cannot reference an identifier before its definition
> (“hello”)
. . “hello”: undefined;
 cannot reference an identifier before its definition
> (define hello “hello”)
. . “hello”: undefined;
 cannot reference an identifier before its definition`code`

Comment: take a screenshot of the entire window

Comment: How do I upload the screenshot?

Comment: CLISP does not take a string without assigning it to a var. Gambit will return “a” if “a” is entered. I also tried BSL abd ASL. I know I am holding a gross conceptual error.

Comment: Could it be that you have copy pasted "hello" from a web page and the " is the wrong character? Did you type in "hello" or copy-paste?

Comment: I will try that. "isthistherightquote"...that is the quote appropriate. Yes, that seems to work.